# Passing XML in variable to curl payload in shell giving error "Error reading XMLStreamReader."

Tags: xml, web-services, shell, curl, soap

Getting Error reading XMLStreamReader. when executing following shell script

```
> #!/bin/sh
> 
> read -d '' delete_payload <<"EOF" 
><soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:typ="http://someurl.com/vi/ma">    <soapenv:Header/>   
> <soapenv:Body>
>       <typ:DecommissionRequest>
>          <typ:Credentials>
>             <typ:Source></typ:Source>
>             <typ:Username></typ:Username>
>             <typ:Password></typ:Password>
>          </typ:Credentials>
>          <typ:PeerHmIP>Secondary_IP</typ:PeerHmIP>
>       </typ:DecommissionRequest>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
> EOF
> 
> 
> resp=$(curl -ks \
>                 -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" \
>                 -H "SOAPAction:Delete" \
>                 -d $delete_payload \
>                 https://serverip:8080/vi)
>echo "$resp"
```

OutPut is

> soap:Client Error
>   reading
>   XMLStreamReader.

Comment: add --trace dumpfile.txt to the curl command line to see exactly what it sends. My guess is the quotes in the XML confuses the shell or something

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your suggestion, yes quotes are there in request== Info: getaddrinfo(3) failed for xmlns:soapenv="http::80
== Info: Couldn't resolve host 'xmlns:soapenv="http:'
== Info: Closing connection #0
== Info: getaddrinfo(3) failed for xmlns:typ="http::80
== Info: Couldn't resolve host 'xmlns:typ="http:'